# Is there a way to create a Menu with multiple choices using f# ? Through passing commands

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I'm new to F# and I am currently creating a Menu to implement in the program I am coding but I find it a bit difficult at the moment. Is there any way to have a menu that ask for input for the user in a loop until exit?

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
open System

let printMenu () =
    printfn "Menu: "
    printfn "1. Do this"
    printfn "2. Do that"
    printfn "3. Exit"
    printf "Enter your choise: "

let getInput () = Int32.TryParse (Console.ReadLine())

let doThis () = printfn "Do this..."
let doThat () = printfn "Do that..."

let rec menu () =
    printMenu()
    match getInput() with
    | true, 1 -> 
        doThis()
        menu()
    | true, 2 -> 
        doThat()
        menu()
    | true, 3 -> ()
    | _ -> menu()


menu ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be to put it into a recursive loop:

```
open System

[<EntryPoint>] let main argv =
    let rec waitForInput() =
        Console.WriteLine("Hello. Type X for Exit.")
        let input = Console.ReadLine()
        match input with 
        | "a" -> waitForInput()
        | "b" -> waitForInput()
        | "X" -> ()
        | _ -> waitForInput()


    waitForInput()

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

This will exit on X. Otherwise ask again.